# Deleting own app's created Image throws SecurityException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-contentresolver

I've a `Bitmap` which converted into **URI** by doing something like this

```
fun bitmapToUri(ctx: Context, bitmap: Bitmap): Uri {
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ByteArrayOutputStream())
    val fileName = "${ctx.getString(R.string.app_name)}-${System.currentTimeMillis()}"
    val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(ctx.contentResolver, bitmap, fileName, "blah blah")
    return Uri.parse(path)
}
```

> So, somewhere I've heard that If your application created some media in my case **IMAGE**.
> You can delete without requiring any permission after API LEVEL - 30 ( Android 11 ). However I've added permission in **Manifest**

So I'm deleting a file or better **Image** from URI like this ( Let me know If I can also delete in other ways. Target SDK - 30)

```
fun deleteUri(context: Context, uri: Uri) {
    val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
    contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null)
}
```

Calling this function in some secret place just kidding in **MainActivity** like this -

```
uri = bitmapToUri(this@MainActivity, bitmap)

...
// I assure you uri is not null
coroutineScope.launch {
    deleteUri(this@MainActivity, uri)
}
...
```

I'm getting a SecurityException :(

```
Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.myapp has no access to content://media/external/images/media/1000000077
at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.enforceCallingPermissionInternal(MediaProvider.java:9959)
at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.enforceCallingPermission(MediaProvider.java:9856)
at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.deleteInternal(MediaProvider.java:5878)
at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.delete(MediaProvider.java:5767)
.... and some more
```

> I've also added file provider in Manifest
>
> ```
> <provider
>    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
>    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
>    android:exported="false"
>    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
>    tools:replace="android:authorities">
>       <meta-data
>           android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
>           android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
>           tools:replace="android:resource" />
>  </provider>
> ```

P.S - I'm testing in Emulator - Pixel 6 API 33, also new on on StackOverflow so please be easy

If you have any question don't hesitate to shoot comment :)

Comment: "I've a Bitmap which converted into URI by doing something like this" -- perhaps instead you should be using `FileProvider`. "So I'm deleting a file or better Image from URI like this" -- you no longer have rights to the content identified by that `Uri`. You would not have this problem if you were using `FileProvider`. "I've also added file provider in Manifest" -- you are not using it, though. Just having the manifest entry is insufficient.

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) covers the use of `FileProvider`. FWIW, I also cover it in [this section](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-005.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for instant reply. I'd like to know more can you please add code snippet

Comment: @CommonsWare how can I convert bitmap to uri using `FileProvider` any idea ?

Comment: Save the bitmap to a file, such as in `getFilesDir()` on `Context`. Use `FileProvider` to make it available to other apps, assuming that you need to do that for some reason.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you I'd like to implement this. Then Can I able to delete after that ?

Comment: You have complete read/write/delete access to files in `getFilesDir()` on `Context`. You can delete them whenever you want.

Comment: If you save something to the mediastore and you got an uri in return then of course you can use that uri to delete the file.

Comment: @blackapps Yeah I've used `MediaStore` as you can see in question but still getting exception while deleting

Comment: We dont see you using the same uri. Please post better example code.

Comment: @blackapps I'm actually storing all created Uri in a list and then getting one of those

Comment: To demonstrate you problem here do away with the list and use one file one uri. Reproducable code is asked here.